# Cross Join Query with Dates

Tags: sql, cross-join

I have following table result.

**Column A**  **Column B**

```
abc            a
xyz            b
pqr            c
```

Now with specific date range i.e. 2018-09-01 to 2018-09-10 I want cross join with these dates with result as below. How to achieve this ?

```
**Date**          **Column A**   **Column B**

2018-09-01         abc            a
2018-09-01         xyz            b
2018-09-01         pqr            c
2018-09-02         abc            a
2018-09-02         xyz            b
2018-09-02         pqr            c
2018-09-03         abc            a
2018-09-03         xyz            b
2018-09-03         pqr            c
.
.
.
2018-09-010        abc            a
2018-09-010        xyz            b
2018-09-010        pqr            c
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. Also, is this a table of dates or do they need to be generated?

Comment: `select * from table1 cross join datestable`. (Where datestable can be a base table or cte.)

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
 declare @sdate date = '2018-09-01'
    , @edate date = '2018-09-10'

; with dates_CTE (date) as (
        select @sdate 
    Union ALL
        select DATEADD(day, 1, date)
        from dates_CTE
        where date < @edate
) ,
t2 as
(
select 'abc' as col1, 'a' as  col2 
union all
select 'xyz','b'
union all
select 'pqr','c'       

) select * from t2 cross join dates_CTE


col1    col2    date
abc     a   01/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   01/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   01/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   02/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   02/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   02/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   03/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   03/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   03/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   04/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   04/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   04/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   05/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   05/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   05/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   06/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   06/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   06/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   07/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   07/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   07/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   08/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   08/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   08/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   09/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   09/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   09/09/2018 00:00:00
abc     a   10/09/2018 00:00:00
xyz     b   10/09/2018 00:00:00
pqr     c   10/09/2018 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the dates.  Most databases support a syntax such as:

```
select dates.dte, t1.a, t1.b
from (select cast('2018-09-01' as date) as dte union all
      select cast('2018-09-02' as date) as dte union all
      . . .
      select cast('2018-09-10' as date) as dte
     ) dates cross join
     table1 t1
order by date, a, b;
```

If you have a calendar table, then use that instead.

Also, some databases might require a `from dual` or `from sysibm.sysdummy1` in the subqueries.  Or they might have other methods for generating a sequence of dates.